# Looking for an easy to read chassidic commentary on the Torah

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, commentaries, chasidut-hasidism

I'm looking for an easy to read chassidic comentary on the Torah. I'm looking for a single commentary. Iwas considering to buy Imrei Noam by the Dzikov rebbe, but I'm not sure if it is easy to read.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76252/good-sefer-on-chassidus

Answer (score 7):

As @sam said his comment, the [Nesivos Shalom](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/nesivas-sholom---5-volume-set-S140914.html) is a classic. It's been [translated to English](https://mekorjudaica.com/gems-from-the-nesivos-shalom-5-vol-chumash-set.html) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The following seforim are usually easier to understand. Please keep in mind that sometimes they will involve kabbalistic teachings that might be harder to understand.

1. שם משמואל by the Sochatshover Rebbe
2. ישמח ישראל by the Alexander Rebbe

More contemporary

1. מפי ספרים וסופרים by Rabbi Friedman
2. שפע חיים ,שיעורי חומש רש"י by the Klausenburger Rebbe
3. באר החיים - Rabbi Elimelech Biederman's weekly Divrey Torah available in English and Hebrew [here](http://ladaat.info/gilyonot.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the teachings of the Lubavitcher Rebbe, many authors authored adaptions from his works. One of these are:

- [Crown Jewels](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2618440/jewish/Crown-Jewels.htm)- Conceptual Frontiers of Chasidic Thought by the Lubavitcher Rebbe
- [Likkutei Sichos](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/68159/jewish/Likkutei-Sichot.htm) by the Lubavitcher Rebbe;

There are several options that are free (English or Hebrew), and can be found at [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Chasidut). One I would recommend is Kedushas Levi. It is not completely "easy" to understand, but it might be worth looking at it.

- [Kedushat Levi](https://www.sefaria.org/Kedushat_Levi?tab=contents) by Rabbi Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev

Comment: I wouldn't recommend most of those to a beginner as many are heavily kabbalistic and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Kehot Chumash. Beginners will understand it, but there is still plenty of depth too. It's available online for free. You can check it out, before deciding to buy a printed edition. It has a link for the overview on the parsha (very well written and based on Chassidus), a separate link for interpolated translation, and a third link called "Chassidic Insight for Parshah" which might be just what you want: https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/927725/jewish/Chassidic-Insights.htm

Answer (score 1):

My Chabad Rav keeps screaming at me to start using these sites:

https://learnchassidus.com/lessons

https://chassidutbehirah.com/

And to start learning Torah Ohr and Likutei Torah, which is the Alter Rebbe's deep intellectual chassidic commentary on the parashiot. You have amazing sheets that translate everything on the first link.

Answer (score 0):

From the excerpts that I've read, Divrei Yoel of the Satmar Rebbe seems easy to read with very nice ideas, and it is very clear.